# Reference schema elements of an imported wsdl

Tags: java, web-services, xpath, wsdl

I have a WSDL which imports another one. The one that is imported contains the schema. The problem is that since this WSDL is imported, the schema is not accessible on  the first one's DOM, and thus i can't reference it with XPATH on my bindings files. Can anyone help me with this? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Xpath only references the DOM of the current file it is analysing. If your WSDL imports another WSDL, for some reason XPATH won't analyse the imported WSDL. you have to copy the schema definitions, portType or whatever else you need to pick with XPATH and put these on the WSDL that imports the second one. That's how i solved this.